# $location.path() redirect doesn't always work in authHttpResponseInterceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-http-interceptors

In my Angular SPA, I have a `authHttpResponseInterceptor` defined as follows:

```
app.factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', 'baseUrl', function ($q, $location, baseUrl) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log('Response 401');
            }
            else if (response.status === 409) {
                $location.path('/sessionexpired');
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                window.location.href = baseUrl + 'Account/Logout';
            }
            else if (rejection.status === 409) {
                $location.path('/sessionexpired');
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I add the interceptor to my $httpProvider like this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
```

If I get a 409 HTTP status from the server, I want to change the location to my `sessionexpired` path.  For some reason, this only occasionally works.

I have the following routes defined:

```
.when('/sessionexpired',
{
    controller: 'sessionExpiredController',
    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Content/templates/409.html'
})
.when('/error',
{
    templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Content/templates/500.html'
})
```

I'm currently debugging the `authHttpResponseInterceptor` when it's not directing to the `sessionexpired` route.  It simply steps over the `$location.path()` line, never gets into the `sessionExpiredController` controller, and ends up on the `error` page.

Any ideas?

Comment: You left out where you add the interceptor to your $httpProvider.

Comment: It looks fine really, although I do not use the exact same structure as you: http://pastebin.com/ddR6gnhy . Try copying that one and change the `Schools` to `sessionexpired`. Not that I expect it to work, just hard to guess without any testable code in front of me. You need to add your base url to the dependencies being injected.